# vim shell output with less

Tags: vim

I have python a code in vim, run it in vim command line, like this:

```
:!python %
```

Output is big enough for screen need scrolling to read it all, but vim only display the output with `more` command to page output, can I change this? use `less` command to page output.

I can run command with the `less` using pipe,

```
:!python % | less
```

but it seems not handy, have to quit twice to leave.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `.vimrc`:

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=shellcmd R new | setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile | r !<args>
```

Example usage:

```
:R python #
```

Explanation:

`:R` opens a new buffer and reads the output of the shell command into it. Because the shell command will be executed for THAT buffer and not the current buffer, we need to use `#` to refer to the current buffer.